# How to find the end tag line number?

Tags: c#, html

I need kind favor to find the closing tag line number. For example:

```
<tr>
  <td>...</td>
  <td>...</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>...</td>
  <td>...</td>

<tr>
  <td>...</td>
  <td>...</td>
</tr>
```

In that above line, the first `<tr>` tag is opened and closed correspondingly.  In the second `<tr>` it is opened but not closed. Without closing the `<tr>` it open third `<tr>`. In this situation I need to show the line number as error. I can find the line number open tag. I need to find the closing tag line number. I am working in WPF C#.

Comment: If you don't care about attributes, that should be very easy. **What have you tried?**

Comment: It would be nice to have a bit more context.  What are you trying to do this for?

Answer (score 2):

You need to put them on "stack" while parsing. Push to your stack when having an open tag, remove in reverse order when a closing tag happen. If close-tag <> open tag type you have an error.

Count lines while parsing and when a mismatch occur print the line-number you're at. Count line numbers by counting line-feeds (char 10 for Windows/Linux, use 13 for Mac).

Compare closing tags with `"/" + opening-tag`

Stack (pesudo-representation to show the "mechanics"):

```
Parser res   Current stack
----------   -------------
Found TR  -> TR
Found TD  -> TR-TD
Found /TD -> TR (it matched last tag on stack) 
Found TD  -> TR-TD
Found /TD -> TR (it matched last tag on stack) 
Found /TR ->  (it matched last tag on stack - stack is empty, all ok) 

Found TR  -> TR
Found TD  -> TR-TD
Found /TD -> TR (it matched last tag on stack) 
Found TD  -> TR-TD
Found /TD -> TR (it matched last tag on stack) 
Found TR  -> TR (mismatch! /+TR <> TR as expected), print error + line number
```

Comment: I'm upvoting this purely based on the mechanical representation :)

Comment: Thanks,I was happy with the mechanics. Hope it will be understandable too ;)